# How to strip html tags out of selection

Tags: javascript, highlight

I want to strip html tags out of a selected text which is inside a content editable div. Lets say selected text is something like this:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <span style="color:red">some text</span>
</div>
```

So I tried this:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
```

but I get an error that says replace is not a function. I tried also this below:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.remove();
```

but this will remove also the text. Whats the deal here?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use `.innerText` ?

Comment: but how can I swap it in there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove only html tags in a string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164335/how-to-remove-only-html-tags-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: sorry but this is not a string, its a selection.

Comment: @CainNuke `document.querySelector(...).innerText`

Comment: `parentNode` is an element object not html string

Comment: okay but then how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
const editable = document.querySelector('div');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(editable.innerText);
});
```

```html
   <div contenteditable="true">
    <span style="color:red">some text</span>
   </div>
   
   <button>Show me the text</button>
```